# Does insert_id() in Codeigniter return false on query failure?

Tags: codeigniter

What does insert_id() return after a failed insert?

Comment: Assuming you're on MySQL, that'd be a pass-through to mysql's last_insert_id(), which returns the ID of the last **SUCCESSFUL** insert (even if that insert was part of a transaction that was rolled back).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that depends of the driver you use. In mysql case the function definition is:

```
/**
* Insert ID
*
* @access   public
* @return   integer
*/
function insert_id()
{
    return @mysql_insert_id($this->conn_id);
}
```

Now reading about `mysql_insert_id`:

> mysql_insert_id  (PHP 4, PHP 5) Get the ID generated in the last query
>
> Parameters:
>   resource $link_identifier [optional]
>
> Returns:
>   Type: int
>
> Description: The ID generated for an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success, 0 if the
>   previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value, or false if
>   no MySQL connection was established.

1.- So it could return an ID, 0 (zero) or false.
2.- And as you ask for a `failed insert` it should return 0 (zero).

---

Note that have an `at sign (@)` error operator that will ignore any error message returned by the `mysql_insert_id` PHP function.

Comment: So in codeigniter you'd probably want to test like this: `if ($this->db->insert_id() != 0)` since `0 == false`.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the database drivers themselves, each version of `insert_id` is implemented differently depending upon the underlying database. For example, the [MySQL `insert_id` function](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php)  is just a wrapper around [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php), which returns:

> The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success, 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

On the other hand, the [postgres function](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/postgre/postgre_driver.php) explicitly returns an ID (although I suppose an exception might be thrown if the query itself failed):

```
    $query = $this->query($sql);
    $query = $query->row();
    return (int) $query->ins_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

most codeigniter functions return false if they don't have a value to give you. I mean it wouldn't return the insert_id because there is no insert_id to give because of an error.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the id only when perfroming database insertion.

In case of success it will generate AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query
In case of failur it returns 0 
Returns FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.